# php Mysql Rows Merging from one table

Tags: php, mysql

Is there a way to *merge* only the last **personal_id's** where i have values in the columns?
Lets say Anderson with the p_id 2 get married and his name changes.

```
id  p_id        last_name   job         Hobby
1   1           Smith       Programmer  NULL
2   2           Anderson    Influencer  Reading
3   2           McKing      Influencer  NULL
4   3           Jordan      Mother      Cooking
5   1           Smith       NULL        Soccer
```

For example that i get:

> p_id: 1 - Smith - Programmer - Soccer
>   p_id: 2 - McKing - Influencer
>   - Reading

Thanks in advance.

Update:

You guys are really strict.

I have tried a couple of queries but i can't achieve my goal.

> SELECT * FROM table GROUP_BY p_id ORDER_BY id ASC

Comment: _Is there a way to "merge" only the last personal_id's where i have values in the columns?_ Yes...what have you tried to achieve that?

Comment: Read [How to Ask a Good Question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE QUEST  (
    id        INT NOT NULL,
    p_id      INT NOT NULL,
    last_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    job       VARCHAR(50),
    hobby     VARCHAR(50));  

INSERT INTO quest VALUES (1,1,'Smith','Programmer',NULL );
INSERT INTO quest VALUES (2,2,'Anderson','Influencer','Reading' );
INSERT INTO quest VALUES (3,2,'McKing','Influencer', NULL );
INSERT INTO quest VALUES (4,3,'Jordan','Mother','Cooking' );
INSERT INTO quest VALUES (5,1,'Smith',NULL,'Soccer' );
INSERT INTO quest VALUES (6,3,'Jordan','Mother','Cooking' );
INSERT INTO quest VALUES (7,4,'John',NULL,NULL );
INSERT INTO quest VALUES (8,5,'Mike','Test',NULL );
INSERT INTO quest VALUES (9,5,'Mick','Tester',NULL );
COMMIT;


SELECT q.p_id,
  q.last_name,
  (SELECT job FROM Quest WHERE job IS NOT NULL AND p_id = q.p_id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1) job,
  (SELECT hobby FROM Quest WHERE hobby IS NOT NULL AND p_id = q.p_id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1) hobby
FROM Quest q
WHERE id IN (SELECT MAX(id) FROM Quest GROUP BY P_Id )
ORDER BY p_id;


Result:
p_id - last_name - job - hobby
1 - Smith - Programmer - Soccer
2 - McKing - Influencer - Reading
3 - Jordan - Mother - Cooking
4 - John - NULL - NULL
5 - Mick - Tester - NULL
```

Comment: Really nice Solutions. And its working pretty nice - Thank You ! @ShashshankKatiyar

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t.last_name, t.job, t.hobby
 FROM {THE_TABLE) as t
 JOIN {THE_TABLE} as t2 on t2.p_id = t.p_id
WHERE t.job is not null
 AND t.hobby is not null
```